# How can I get input field data before click submit button in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Actually I need this for form validation and want to check it live before submit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "onchange" event for each input to validate input, and when the user click on "submit" check that all inputs fileds are valid and not empty.

```
<input type='text' onchange="validate_function();" />
<script>
function validate_function() {
    /*Do your magic here...*/
}
</script>
```

EDIT:

**Solution 2**

You can use css validations. You can read about this method here:

https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-ux-html-css/

Comment: Submit button is disable when all data is valid it will be enable. @KorelK

Comment: In this case you can use two solutions: 1. Every change check the all the inputs. 2. Use inputs status array inside js, and update the status of each one. Then in evety change, if the current input that change is valid, update the array and check if all others inputs are valid too.

Comment: You're welcome. One more thing, I edited the comment and inserted another solution. It is always good to learn new ways.